# Get top of remote file in Swift

Tags: swift, file, url, partial

There is a line in multiple files via the Internet.  I want to avoid download the entire file.  Each file may be long or short.  The required line is usually about line 15 - always different, but always within the first 500 bytes.

Is there a way I can get just the top part of a remote file?

I can then use a regex pattern to find the required line.

Although I know how to download a file in a temp. location and copy it to a proper location, I think that process is too much and wasteful.
This is an example:

```
class func load(url: URL, to localUrl: URL, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    let request = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .get)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Success: \(statusCode)")
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: localUrl)
                completion()
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("error writing file \(localUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Failure: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

PS. It would also be helpful if you could include a method to find a line beginning with, say "abc=xyz", where I want "xyz".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only download partial content, you need a server that supports sending ranges. To test this, make a `HEAD` request and check if the server responds with an `Accept-Range: bytes` header. If so, you can request partial content by adding a header like `Range: bytes=0-499` to your `GET` requests to only receive the initial 500 bytes.

Comment: That makes sense!  Do you happen to have an example script?  I never done a HEAD request before...

Comment: Simply use `curl --head YOUR_URL`

Comment: @YumaTechnicalInc. you should use dataTask not downloadTask if you want to download only the HEAD of a file

Comment: @LeoDabus. Thanks, I'll try it...  Do you have a better example method?